# For a regular sequence $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $J= (x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})$ show that $x_ny \in J^{j}M$ implies $y\in J^{j-1}M$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and let $M$ be an $R$-module. Let $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ be an $M$-regular sequence, and let $J = (x_1,\dots, x_{n-1})$ be the ideal generated by the first $n-1$ elements.

How does one prove that $x_ny\in J^jM$ for some $j>1$ implies that $y\in J^{j-1}M$. I can see this is true for $j=2$, but I can't see how the induction step goes.

Bruns and Herzog, Cohen-Macaulay rings, claim this is true by induction, on page 6, in the proof of Theorem 1.1.7 (which is the proof of Rees's theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're arguing that $x_n$ is regular on $M/J^jM$ by induction on $j$. If $x_n y \in J^j M$ then $x_n y \in J^{j-1}M$ as well, because $J^j \subseteq J^{j-1}$. The induction hypothesis says $x_n$ is  regular on $M/J^{j-1}M$, so $x_n y \in J^{j-1}M$ implies $y \in J^{j-1}M$.

Comment: I don't completely follow this argument. You are arguing that $x_n$ is regular on $M/J^jM$ by induction on $j$. So you are assuming that $x_n$ is regular on $M/J^{j-1}M$. However, you use the inductive hypothesis to show that ``if $x_n$ is regular on $M/J^{j-1}M$, then $y \in J^{j-1}M$''. But don't you need to show that $x_n$ is regular on $M/J^{j}M$ for this induction to work? 

I certainly buy that if $x_n$ is regular on $M/J^jM$ then the original statement follows.

Comment: Are you asking why I finished by proving $y \in J^{j-1}$ and not that $y \in J^{j}$? If so, this is a small chunk of a larger argument inside of an induction on the number of variables $n$. In fact the Lemma OP asked about in their question is proven using the outer induction hypothesis. I was just explaining the step of the lemma OP was confused about.

Comment: I found the logical structure of the argument in Bruns and Herzog difficult to parse when reading and had to rewrite the argument step by step and understand exactly what we were inducting on/trying to prove at every step